# wrong output searching in binary files using seekg() & seekp()

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I wrote this very simple code but its search section does not work.

I just saved the names and ages of the people in a binary file and I want to find them , it gives me the wrong record.

it's search part:

```
fstream myfile(filename , ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);

data d;


int searchage;


cout << "age : ";
cin >> searchage;


myfile.seekg(sizeof(data)* (searchage) );

myfile.read((char*)&d , sizeof(data));

myfile.close();

cout << "name : " << d.getname() << '\t' << d.getage() << endl;
```

you may need the class  :

```
    class data{

private:
    int age;
    char name[15];


public:


    data (){
    // null

    }
    void setname(string tempname){
    int len = tempname.size();
    len = (len < 15 ? len : 14);
    tempname.copy(name , len);

    name[len] = '\0';

    }

    string getname(){
    return name;
    }



    void setage(int tempage){
    age = tempage;
    }


    int getage(){

    return age;
    }

};
```

and saving part :

```
fstream myfile(filename , ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);


data d;

string name ;
int age;


cout << "name : ";
cin >> name;

cout << "age : ";
cin >> age;


d.setname(name);
d.setage(age);



myfile.seekp(sizeof(data) * age , ios::beg);

myfile.write((char*)&d , sizeof(data));

myfile.close();
```

also whole code is here

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

#define filename "D:\\data.dat"


class data{

private:
    int age;
    char name[15];


public:


    data (string tempname = "null" , int tempage = 1){

    setname(tempname);
    setage(tempage);

    }
    void setname(string tempname){
    int len = tempname.size();
    len = (len < 15 ? len : 14);
    tempname.copy(name , len);

    name[len] = '\0';

    }

    string getname(){
    return name;
    }



    void setage(int tempage){
    age = tempage;
    }


    int getage(){

    return age;
    }

};



int main(){

 int a;

    cout << "1 - save \n2 - search \nchose : ";
   
    cin >> a;

    if(a == 1){

        fstream myfile("D:\\data.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::app);


        data d , d2;

        if(!myfile)
        {
            cout << "creat file \n";
            ofstream myfile2(filename , ios::out | ios::binary);

            myfile2.write((char*)&d2 , sizeof(data));

            myfile2.close();
        }

        fstream myfile3(filename , ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in | ios::app);


        string name ;
        int age;


        cout << "name : ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "age : ";
        cin >> age;


        d.setname(name);
        d.setage(age);



        myfile3.seekp(sizeof(data) * age , ios::beg);

        myfile3.write((char*)&d , sizeof(data));

        myfile3.close();

    }else if(a == 2){
        fstream myfile(filename , ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in);

        data d;


        int searchage;


        cout << "age : ";
        cin >> searchage;


        myfile.seekg(sizeof(data)* searchage );

        myfile.read((char*)&d , sizeof(data));

        myfile.close();

        cout << "name : " << d.getname() << '\t' << d.getage() << endl;


    }







}
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What happens when you test the *stream-state* after your attempted `seekp()`, e.g. `if (! myfile.seekp(sizeof(data) * age , ios::beg)) { std::cerr << "error: seekp() failed.\n"; /* handle error */ }` ?? In other words, what do you think happens when `myfile` is **empty** and you call `myfile.seekp(sizeof(data) * age , ios::beg)` ?

Comment: Well the information will be stored in a partitioned space

Comment: `fstream.read()` returns a value. You are ignoring it. Don't.

Comment: Is there always exactly one `data` object with a given age 0, 1, ..., age/searchage?

Comment: @mehdy.n Okay, you are saying your file isn't empty? It has either some file or memory backed storage to begin with? Conceivably that will work, but that code isn't shown. Please take a look at [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: no there is two parts for saving and searching . I'll add whole code

Comment: @David C. Rankin
This is a problem because it has no warnings or errors, it just returns an empty record, also I have added the whole code here.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at the updated code. How big is `data.dat`? Is there a way  you can post a link to it? Why is `name` type `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @mehdy.n If you are still having problems after reading through the answer, drop a comment. You should work toward only opening the file once, and retrieving the total number of bytes from which you can calculate the number of `data` records contained in the file. (seek end, then `tellp() / sizeof(data)`)  I have intentionally left that for you to explore. (since file is open in `binary` mode, `tellg()` returns the number of bytes). You only need. `myfile` (not `myfile2/3`) Since you are not looping, no need to close it, that will happen on exit. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @David C. Rankin                   Yessss, thank you, the problem is solved with your solution and the program works as it should

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no way the code above will compile without error or warning. Specifically due to your use of:

```cpp
    void setname(string tempname){
      ...
      tempname.copy(name , len);
```

The `.copy()` member function is not a member of `std::string`, but instead a member of `std::basic_string_view` (C++17). The compiler does not know what `.copy()` is in that circumstance. Instead, you need to use `std::basic_string_view<char>` as the type for `tempname`, e.g.

```cpp
  void setname (std::basic_string_view<char> tempname) {
    int len = tempname.size();
    len = (len < 15 ? len : 14);
    tempname.copy(name , len);
    name[len] = '\0';
  }
```

(**note:** `len` should be type `size_t`)

Your constructor can use the same approach to fill `name`, e.g.

```cpp
  data (std::basic_string_view<char> tempname = "null" , int tempage = 1) : 
  age{tempage} {
    tempname.copy (name, tempname.size());
  }
```

While use of `char[]` instead of `std::string` should be avoided, it is clear that is used in `data` to ensure a fixed-size object with one 15-char C-string and one `int`)

**Basic Problem with `.seekp()` and `.seekg()` - `age` Is Not An Offset**

As mentioned in the comment above, when you save, unless `D:\\data.dat` has at least `age` number of objects already stored in the file, your save and search will attempt to move the file position indicator beyond the end of the file with. This will absolutely occur if you attempt to search before a save when your file doesn't exist. For example:

```cpp
    myfile3.seekp (sizeof(data) * age , std::ios::beg);
```

In the case of `if (!myfile) { ... }` there is only a single `data` object written to the file. That is created here:

```cpp
      myfile2.write((char*)&d2 , sizeof(data));
```

That writes `d2` only to the file.

In the case of search, the same problem applies. When you read `searchage` you have no guarantee that there are at least that many `data` objects in the file. You need some way to ensure you have valid data to read.  As mentioned in the comment, one way to ensure that `seekp()` and `seekg()` succeed is to check the stream-state (the return) from each call. See [std::basic_ostream::seekp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) (and the same for `seekg()`)

For example, after a single output is written to the file, attempting to search will attempt to `seekg()` beyond the end of the file with:

```cpp
    myfile.seekg (sizeof(data)* searchage );
```

Checking if `failbit` is set will tell you if your seek succeeded. As it currently is, `seekg()` leaves the read-position indicator at the end of the file and you read nothing. (but since you don't check the stream state after the read -- you likewise don't know it is failing)

(simply commenting out the `seekg()` call will allow you to read your first record back in)

To fix the issue with `seekg()`, you need to keep track of the number of `data` objects available in your file (say `n`) and only offset at most `(n - 1) * sizeof(data)`  bytes from the beginning. If overwriting existing data, then you need to limit `seekp()` by the same amount, otherwise just seek the end of the file to write a new object to file.

Without your sample input, there is no way to test your file. However, fixing the issues above your code does create an empty file and writes `name` and `age` to the file that after commenting out your `seekg()` call are read back into the program into `d` just fine.... For example, changing your search code to the following minimally validated checks for `seekg()` and `read()` will allow you to read the record number (`data` object number) from your file. `record` is used instead of `searchage` below:

```cpp
  else if (a == 2) {
    std::fstream myfile (filename , std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | 
                                    std::ios::in);

    data d;
    int record;

    std::cout << "record no. : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> record)) {
      std::cerr << "error: invalid input - record.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    if (!myfile.seekg (sizeof(data)* (record - 1))) {
      std::cerr << "error: seekg() failed.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    if (!myfile.read ((char*)&d , sizeof(data))) {
      std::cerr << "error: read failed.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    myfile.close();

    std::cout << "name : " << d.getname() << '\t' << d.getage() << '\n';
  }
```

**Example Use/Output**

With two records written to a data file (`"Henry", 10` and `"Mike", 20`), the data can be retrieved without any problems using the correct record offset, e.g.

```
$ hexdump -Cv dat/nameage.dat
00000000  0a 00 00 00 48 65 6e 72  79 00 f8 2e fd 7e 00 00  |....Henry....~..|
00000010  01 c9 d9 2e 14 00 00 00  4d 69 6b 65 00 5e 7b 17  |........Mike.^{.|
00000020  2c 7f 00 00 01 b9 5c 17                           |,.....\.|
00000028
```

The first can be read with:

```
$ ./bin/name_age
1 - save
2 - search
chose : 2
record no. : 1
name : Henry    10
```

and the second with:

```
$ ./bin/name_age
1 - save
2 - search
chose : 2
record no. : 2
name : Mike     20
```

Attempting to read more data than exists, generates an error, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/name_age
1 - save
2 - search
chose : 2
record no. : 3
error: read failed.
```

**Working Example - Retrieve No. of `data` Records from File**

Cleaning up the code a bit so you only need open a single file and getting the size in bytes to compute the number of `data` records available in the file so you can prevent attempting to seek beyond the end of your file, you could do something similar to the following. Note you must set your compiler language standard to C++17. Also note, with the number of `data` records known -- there is no reason to write an empty `data` struct to the file. You simply add a check to your `search` code to check if the waned records is available, and handle the error if it is not:

```cpp
/* requires compiling with the C++17 language standard */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>

#define filename "D:\\data.dat"
#define MAXNAME  15

class data {

 private:
  int age;
  char name[MAXNAME];

 public:

  data (std::basic_string_view<char> tempname = "null" , int tempage = 1) : 
  age{tempage} {
    tempname.copy (name, tempname.size());
  }
  
  void setname (std::basic_string_view<char> tempname) {
    int len = tempname.size();
    len = (len < 15 ? len : 14);
    tempname.copy(name , len);
    name[len] = '\0';
  }

  std::string getname() { return name; }
  void setage (int tempage) { age = tempage; }
  int getage() { return age; }
};

int main() {

  int a;
  size_t nrecords = 0;        /* number of records in file */
  data d;

  /* open file in r/w, bin, app mode (a+b), will create if doesn't exist */
  std::fstream myfile (filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::in | 
                                 std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

  if (!myfile.is_open()) {    /* validate file is open */
    std::cerr << "error: file open/create failed.\n";
    return 1;
  }
  
  myfile.seekp (0, std::ios::end);            /* seek to end */
  nrecords = myfile.tellp() / sizeof(data);   /* get number of records */
  
  std::cout << "File number of records : " << nrecords << "\n\n";
  
  if (!nrecords)  /* if no records, new file */
    std::cout << "creat file \n";   /* optional - your output */
  
  std::cout << "1 - save \n2 - search \nchose : ";  /* menu */
  
  if (!(std::cin >> a) || a < 1 || 2 < a) {   /* validate EVERY input */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return 1;
  }

  if (a == 1) {     /* save */
    
    std::string name {};
    int age;

    std::cout << "name : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> name)) {    /* validate EVERY input */
      std::cerr << "error: name not read.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "age : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> age)) {     /* validate EVERY input */
      std::cerr << "error: invalid input - age.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    d.setname(name);          /* set class members */
    d.setage(age);
    
    /* validate EVRY write */
    if (!myfile.write ((char*)&d , sizeof(data))) {
      std::cerr << "error: write failed.\n";
      return 1;
    }

  }
  else if (a == 2) {    /* search */
    
    if (nrecords == 0) {      /* validate records available to search */
      std::cout << "file-empty, nothing to search.\n";
      return 1;
    }
    
    size_t record;            /* record number to read */

    std::cout << "record no. : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> record)) {  /* validate EVERY input */
      std::cerr << "error: invalid input - searchage.\n";
      return 1;
    }
    
    if (record > nrecords) {  /* check requested record in range */
      std::cerr << "error: requested record out-of-range.\n";
      return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate seek from beginning */
    if (!myfile.seekg (sizeof(data) * (record - 1))) {
      std::cerr << "error: seekg() failed.\n";
      return 1;
    }
    
    /* validate EVERY read */
    if (!myfile.read ((char*)&d , sizeof(data))) {
      std::cerr << "error: read failed.\n";
      return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "name : " << d.getname() << '\t' << d.getage() << '\n';
  }
}
```

**General Observations**

You need to validate all user-inputs by checking the stream-state after the read. That can be as simple as:

```cpp
  if (!(std::cin >> a)) {   /* validate EVERY input */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return 1;
  }
```

or you can include the value check for `a` as well, e.g.

```cpp
  if (!(std::cin >> a) || a < 1 || 2 < a) {   /* validate EVERY input */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return 1;
  }
```

Including the entire standard namespace in your code is also discouraged. See: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696). Though for an exercise it doesn't hurt, just be aware it should be avoided moving forward.

I'm sure there are additional error that are unable to be tested without input, but those above are the primary issues that will prevent your code from working.